# Should I make a page stateful if contains stateful widget inside it?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am in a confused situation if I should make a page/screen stateful or stateless. Elaborating it, I made a widget named `MyHomePage` which is `MaterialApp`. This contains only one widget which will change its value. That is `Text`.

Now just for only one stateful widget i.e. `Text` here do i have to extend `MyHomePage` from `StatefullWidget` or `StatelessWidget`? I know what is a stateful and stateless widget but I am confused in this type of situation.

Please make my concepts clear.

Answer (score 1):

If the children of your stateless widget are `immutable` i.e don't change, then you should go for using a stateless widget. If you have a `Stateful` widgets children, you shouldn't care about the parent. Because each `StatefulWidget` has an internal state that will update(change the values inside the state) irrespective of the parent widget of the `StatefulWidget`

Answer (score 0):

If the `Text` is going to be changed i.e. showing a different string (after some action like you have a button which changes the text), you need to use `StatefulWidget`.

And if `Text` is not going to be changed (immutable), you can use `StatelessWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could use a *StatelessWidget* with a widget called [StatefulBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) as a parent of `Text`. This widget has a builder parameter with setState callback inside.

(EDITED)